# Viber нет сети ошибка подключения к сервисам

Tags: android, linux, viber

viber нет сети ошибка подключения к сервисам.
интернет есть, версия по новая. в чем может быть проблeма?
не синхронизирует контакты, пытаешься новые добавить пишет - ошибка подключения к сервисам.

может кто сталкивался? на сайтах в яндексе то, что предлагают.. советы использовал непомогло.

может из-за версии android?

Comment: Вот официальная рекомендация:
https://vibir.ru/faq/oshibka-podklyucheniya-k-servisam-messendzhera-viber Здесь описаны возможные причины проблемы. Попробуйте обновить Viber до последней версии.

Comment: что то мне кажется, что этот вопрос не для этого сайта.